# What are the main differences from Mycelium vs GMX perp dex?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, arbitrum

It looks like Mycelium DEX does pretty much what GMX dex does, except for Mycelium offering a few more trading pairs. What are the main differences from these 2 DEXes on Arbitrum and its history if possible?

Answer (score 0):

The differences between GMX and Mycelium Dex:

- GMX is more established than Mycelium in the industry
- GMX uses a customized oracle that enables quick price updates by using CEX pricing, while Mycelium uses price keepers from Binance and FTX, along with external oracles and latent oracle feeds from a proprietary company
- GMX charges a 0.1 % of the notional size opening and closing fee, while Mycelium charges 0.09%
- GMX's long-tail assets have lower spreads than those of Mycelium, which could lead to better execution pricing trading in GMX

See:

https://coinpaper.com/548/gmx-or-mycelium-choosing-the-best-platform-for-derivatives-trading-on-arbitrum

https://www.builder.news/crypto-insights/gmx-exchange

Answer (score 0):

Mycelium is an infrastructure provider, starting on Chainlink in 2019 and today operating a considerable Chainlink Node operation, supporting 11 Blokchains and 1000+ different price feeds, submitting 20 Million successful txns across those chains.

Mycelium is part of the Chainlink BUILD program, were selected as an Arbitrum Validator Node alongside ETH Foundation and ConsenSys. The Validator Role on Arbitrum works alongside the Sequencer and ad min of the protocol contracts themselves to secure the network. So we have been established and building in Defi since the beginning as a respected team.

As for our contracts on Arbitrum, we both use similar Fast Feed Exchange data, with the Chainlink Oracles as a secondary price reference. We use Websockets to ensure a real-time, ongoing communication. We reference price data from Binance, Coinbase and Bitfinex. Mycelium has also built out an RPC for faster execution.

FTX was removed immediately as concerns began about their solvency.

Comment: How does this answer the comparison to GMX perp dex?